# How do I remove the ambiguity in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Christopher planned his vacation at the beach in December.

Without adding a context to specify the meaning of this sentence, it could be read as either **Christopher was at the beach in December, and planned his vacation there** or **Christopher planned his vacation to go to the beach in December**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A time-phrase or place-phrase at the start of the sentence will be understood to modify "Christopher planned", when and where he did the planning:

> At the beach in December, Christopher planned his vacation in the
>   mountains.

and the place-phrase "in the mountains" will be understood to complement "vacation".

> In December, Christopher planned his vacation at the beach.

Comment: Then, you mean my example is not ambiguous, and only the example means Christopher was at the beach in December, and planned his vacation there?

Comment: There is greater ambiguity with your sentence in text than there would necessarily be in speech.  A speaker could disambiguate without having to relocate the phrase to the beginning of the sentence.   *Christopher planned {normal brief syntactic pause} his vacation at the beach {exaggerated syntactic pause} in December.*   Detaching "in December" from "his vacation at the beach" in that manner would indicate that it was adverbial, modifying "planned".

Comment: That exaggerated syntactic pause could be represented in text with a comma: *Christopher planned his vacation at the beach, in December.*